# Cloud Storage images not loading - Flutter, Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

New to flutter, need a page that would display all the images on the Cloud Storage directory. Not working correctly.

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class MyImagePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyImagePageState createState() => _MyImagePageState();
}

class _MyImagePageState extends State<MyImagePage> {
  String? _imageURL = '';

  Future<void> getImageURL() async {
  
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('images')
        .doc('IMG-20230506-WA0010')
        .get();

   
    if (snapshot.exists) {
      String? imageURL = (snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)[
          'url']; // Set the state of the _imageURL variable to trigger a rebuild of the widget tree
      setState(() {
        _imageURL = imageURL;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getImageURL();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Image Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _imageURL == null
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: _imageURL.toString(),
                placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am informed that the code above would not display all the images in the folder, in need for assistance with that too.

My Cloud Storage:

[image]

[image]

Tried changing folders and editing file names - did not anyhow change the result.

Comment: If im guessing correctly, you are using storage for the image. in that case it will `FirebaseStorage` instead of  `FirebaseFirestore`, you can find more about [storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `FirebaseFirestore` and `FirebaseStorage`. You're tyring to load the imageUrl from firestore, where it doesn't exist.

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('images').doc('IMG-20230506-WA0010').get();
```

use `FirebaseStorage` like this:

```
void getUrl()async{
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('images/yourFileName.png');
    String url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    print(url);
  }
```